# How can I get this output in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have been using SQL for around 2 years but I have recently started using Crystal Reports 2013.

I need to convert the below SQL to a Crystal Report:

```
SELECT     COUNT(orders.order_no), reason_codes.reason_desc
FROM       orders, reason_codes
WHERE      orders.reason_code = reason_codes.reason_code
AND        orders_reason.code IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY   reason_codes.reason_desc
```

I'm lost as to how I go about getting the count completed. I am looking for an end result looking like:

```
COUNT(orders.order_no), reason_codes.reason_desc
500                     Broken in Transit
400                     Broken in Warehouse
```

It seems so easy to do it directly in SQL, as I have done above, but getting the desired output in Crystal Reports seems complicated, and I don't know where to start!

Comment: This site is for programming questions, we are not general software tech support.

Comment: @MarcB Have you even looked at some questions at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crystal-reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while creating database connection use command and use the same query exactly there and now in design place your fields in details.